# .htaccess php removal for a subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Currently using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

However moving a php script that uses this to a subfolder and having something else in the main directory.

What's the best way to allow the above to work in the subfolder only?

Comment: Move the .htaccess to the same subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the file to the sub folder along with the php file